# How to organise multiple SoapUI test scenarios to the same REST endpoint?

Tags: test-management, soapui, rest

Let's say I have a REST service that allows you to search for rail journeys - and that once you have selected them, you can book them.
The endpoint is `example.com/service/v1/book`, and to create the booking, you use a `POST`.

Because in reality, when you get to the booking state, the request would require a lot of data, the details of the booking are send as JSON.

For simplicity's sake, let's assume the body just takes the journey legs at the moment:

```
{
    "journey" : {
        "type" : "return",
        "outgoing" : {
            "from" : "LON",
            "to" : "NCL"
        },
        "return" : {
            "from" : "NCL",
            "to" : "LON"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, for a one-way ticket, that bit would obviously look slightly different, **yet the resource (or HTTP method) *wouldn't* change** - it would still be `POST example.com/service/v1/book`:

```
 {
    "journey" : {
        "type" : "single",
        "outgoing" : {
            "from" : "LON",
            "to" : "NCL"
        }
    }
}
```

The service would have to deal with it slightly differently, though. So, we'd want to test both.

How would you structure that in SoapUI?

I thought you'd create the resource (with the POST method), then create two different test cases, "one-way" and "return".

What I'm not sure of is how I'd then be able to pass the different payloads in? And where they'd be defined...?

Comment: Are you using Pro or community, I will assume Pro unless and amend my answer if required.

Comment: The community edition, unfortunately.

Comment: Updated accordingly.  It does mean you will need a case for each route you want to test

Answer (score 2):

I have working in a not dissimilar industry and had the following setup;

TrainTestSuite (this might be per supplier/operator)

-testcase->SingleBooking

-testcase->ReturnBooking

Both would utilize the same endpoint as the Test Suite

Within each test case I would have the following;

- Properties (containing from and to locations)
- PropertyTransfer (Transfer values to JsonSingleRQ using xpath)
- JsonSingleRQ (your JSON request)

Duplicate this for your return journeys (obviously with additional values in the properties).  I would suggest to treat them as independent values rather than transferring to opposing targets on the return.